# Wordpress theme loses widgets during move

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am moving a Worpdress site to a new domain and a new server.

In doing so I have found that the theme is reported as broken until reset in the wp-admin panel.

Not such a problem.

The bigger more annoying problem is that all widgets are de-activated and I cannot for love nor money find a work around for this. I have tried using a searchandreplace on the DB itself to no avail.

All widgets are preserved but they are unset and reside in the inactive widgets area - Not good when a client has over 200 of them.

Answer (score 0):

During migration from one server to another one you can dumb(export) and import mysql database of your website to your new server's DB. Then you must manually edit some rows('site_url' and 'home' option_names) in wp_options table. Then you must copy and paste entire files and folders to new server. Then to edit wp-config.php file. That's all. You Wordpress website will continue from point where stopped in old server. No any data lose or settings change.
I usually use this way and i am very satisfied.